# Can we open amp page in app or can we make app indexed page to come in google search rather than amp pages?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

Google AMP Trumps App Indexing In Google Mobile Search Results? is this true ? But from an update from one of the google employee. App deeplinks will trump AMP this is not happening right now.

search text - if-fr-rarr-r-and-gr-rarr-r-is-given-by-fx-x-and-gxx-for-each-x-in-r-then-x-in-rgfxle-fgx-97810

amp url - https://amp.doubtnut.com/question-answer/if-fr-rarr-r-and-gr-rarr-r-is-given-by-fx-x-and-gxx-for-each-x-in-r-then-x-in-rgfxle-fgx-97810

deeplink url / canonical - https://doubtnut.com/question-answer/if-fr-rarr-r-and-gr-rarr-r-is-given-by-fx-x-and-gxx-for-each-x-in-r-then-x-in-rgfxle-fgx-97810

app link - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubtnutapp&hl=en_IN

Google override's canonical/deeplink with AMP even when I have app installed on mobile.